# Get trending topics from Twitter api

Tags: php, json, twitter

As a php noob I'm trying to solve a problem with Twitter's api. What I want to do is get the Twitter trending topics and display them as a list on a website. What I have so far:

```html
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
 
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "xxxxxx",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxxxxxx",
    'consumer_key' => "xxxxxxxxxx",
    'consumer_secret' => "xxxxxxxxxxx"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = '?id=23424829&count=10';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
foreach($string as $items)
    {
        echo "Hashtag: ".$items['name']."<br />";
        
    }

?>
```

I can get the correct results in JSON and decode them as an array. But as soon as I try to loop around the array with foreach, it shows me a blank page, just showing the "Hashtag:" but no results.

The start of the decoded JSON looks like this:

```html
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [trends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #NakedAttraction
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23NakedAttraction
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23NakedAttraction
                            [tweet_volume] => 
                        )
```

This is the code I used before to decode the JSON:

```html
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
 
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "XXXXXXXXXX",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "XXXXXXXX",
    'consumer_key' => "XXXXXXXX",
    'consumer_secret' => "XXXXXXXXXX"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = '?id=23424829&count=10';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = FALSE);
if($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "") {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($string);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

After changing the code to

```html
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield) ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod) ->performRequest(), TRUE);
var_dump($string);
```

I received this

```html
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["trends"]=> array(49) { [0]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "#NakedAttraction" ["url"]=> string(46) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23NakedAttraction" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(18) "%23NakedAttraction" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(13) "#hartaberfair" ["url"]=> string(43) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23hartaberfair" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(15) "%23hartaberfair" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#EBSFCU" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23EBSFCU" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23EBSFCU" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "#4Blocks" ["url"]=> string(38) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%234Blocks" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(10) "%234Blocks" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [4]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "#LuchaTele5" ["url"]=> string(41) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23LuchaTele5" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(13) "%23LuchaTele5" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [5]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Diego Costa" ["url"]=> string(45) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Diego+Costa%22" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(17) "%22Diego+Costa%22" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(13267) } [6]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "Wochenstart" ["url"]=> string(39) "http://twitter.com/search?q=Wochenstart" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(11) "Wochenstart" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [7]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Deutsche Konzerne" ["url"]=> string(51) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Deutsche+Konzerne%22" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(23) "%22Deutsche+Konzerne%22" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [8]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Session" ["url"]=> string(35) "http://twitter.com/search?q=Session" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(7) "Session" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(69911) } [9]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Schleswig-Holstein" ["url"]=> string(46) "http://twitter.com/search?q=Schleswig-Holstein" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(18) "Schleswig-Holstein" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [10]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#CHEMID" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23CHEMID" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23CHEMID" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(51187) } [11]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(19) "#GoodbyeDeutschland" ["url"]=> string(49) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GoodbyeDeutschland" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(21) "%23GoodbyeDeutschland" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [12]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "#BladeRunner2049" ["url"]=> string(46) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23BladeRunner2049" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(18) "%23BladeRunner2049" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(33497) } [13]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(13) "#DWTStockholm" ["url"]=> string(43) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23DWTStockholm" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(15) "%23DWTStockholm" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(22936) } [14]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "#SallyYates" ["url"]=> string(41) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23SallyYates" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(13) "%23SallyYates" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(247812) } [15]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "#BlognBurger60" ["url"]=> string(44) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23BlognBurger60" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(16) "%23BlognBurger60" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [16]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#Pegida" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Pegida" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23Pegida" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [17]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "#lobo" ["url"]=> string(35) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23lobo" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(7) "%23lobo" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [18]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#usaswe" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23usaswe" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23usaswe" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [19]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "#TheVampsVIP" ["url"]=> string(42) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TheVampsVIP" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(14) "%23TheVampsVIP" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(20397) } [20]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "#LTW17nrw" ["url"]=> string(39) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23LTW17nrw" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(11) "%23LTW17nrw" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [21]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(14) "#NiemalsAllein" ["url"]=> string(44) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23NiemalsAllein" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(16) "%23NiemalsAllein" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [22]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "#Juncker" ["url"]=> string(38) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Juncker" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(10) "%23Juncker" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [23]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(6) "#mcb17" ["url"]=> string(36) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23mcb17" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(8) "%23mcb17" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [24]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "#ltwsh17" ["url"]=> string(38) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ltwsh17" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(10) "%23ltwsh17" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [25]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "#TagderBefreiung" ["url"]=> string(46) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TagderBefreiung" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(18) "%23TagderBefreiung" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [26]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(19) "#Presidentielle2017" ["url"]=> string(49) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Presidentielle2017" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(21) "%23Presidentielle2017" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(216803) } [27]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#GERRUS" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23GERRUS" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23GERRUS" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [28]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "#freubier" ["url"]=> string(39) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23freubier" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(11) "%23freubier" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [29]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#SCFS04" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23SCFS04" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23SCFS04" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [30]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(6) "#dmb17" ["url"]=> string(36) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23dmb17" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(8) "%23dmb17" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [31]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(15) "#Frankreichwahl" ["url"]=> string(45) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Frankreichwahl" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(17) "%23Frankreichwahl" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [32]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(25) "#SignOfTheTimesMusicVideo" ["url"]=> string(55) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23SignOfTheTimesMusicVideo" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(27) "%23SignOfTheTimesMusicVideo" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(396869) } [33]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "#muttertagswunsch" ["url"]=> string(47) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23muttertagswunsch" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(19) "%23muttertagswunsch" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [34]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "#AnneWill" ["url"]=> string(39) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23AnneWill" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(11) "%23AnneWill" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [35]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "#Polizeiruf" ["url"]=> string(41) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Polizeiruf" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(13) "%23Polizeiruf" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [36]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "#Framing" ["url"]=> string(38) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Framing" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(10) "%23Framing" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [37]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#Tuchel" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Tuchel" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23Tuchel" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [38]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(18) "#dasperfektedinner" ["url"]=> string(48) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23dasperfektedinner" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(20) "%23dasperfektedinner" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [39]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(6) "#Fritz" ["url"]=> string(36) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Fritz" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(8) "%23Fritz" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [40]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(19) "#frenchelection2017" ["url"]=> string(49) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23frenchelection2017" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(21) "%23frenchelection2017" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(52362) } [41]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(8) "#tasteup" ["url"]=> string(38) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23tasteup" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(10) "%23tasteup" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [42]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "#Montagslaecheln" ["url"]=> string(46) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Montagslaecheln" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(18) "%23Montagslaecheln" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [43]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#vfbaue" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23vfbaue" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23vfbaue" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [44]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11) "#Kofferraum" ["url"]=> string(41) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23Kofferraum" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(13) "%23Kofferraum" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [45]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(15) "#ParisAgreement" ["url"]=> string(45) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23ParisAgreement" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(17) "%23ParisAgreement" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [46]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "#cl2025" ["url"]=> string(37) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23cl2025" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(9) "%23cl2025" ["tweet_volume"]=> NULL } [47]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(10) "#MTVAwards" ["url"]=> string(40) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23MTVAwards" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(12) "%23MTVAwards" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(1306553) } [48]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(16) "#TattoosForShawn" ["url"]=> string(46) "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TattoosForShawn" ["promoted_content"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(18) "%23TattoosForShawn" ["tweet_volume"]=> int(31256) } } ["as_of"]=> string(20) "2017-05-08T21:46:50Z" ["created_at"]=> string(20) "2017-05-08T21:43:18Z" ["locations"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Germany" ["woeid"]=> int(23424829) } } } }
```

Could any of you wise coding monks be so merciful to help me out?

Comment: What code did you run to get the display of the decoded JSON? Just trying to work out your object/array structure

Comment: Hi Andy, I edited my initial post and included the code I used to decode the JSON and print the array. I guess the solution will be easy for someone like you. But me, as a PHP noob can't get it to work. Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: I'm not totally sure but I think you are trying to use the results as an array but it is coming back as an object. I'm not sure if the parameter passing method works in PHP so try changing `$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);`
to
`$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(), TRUE);`

Comment: Thank's for your help Andy! Unfortunately this didn't work. The result is the same. I can only see "Hashtag:" printed. The rest is empty.

Comment: Ok, so assuming it is now an array, you can't be in the right part of it to loop over. After `$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(), TRUE);` please do `var_dump($string);` and view the page source and show us the result. (Please note the removal of "$assoc =" in the json_decode call)

Comment: Glad to see you didn't gave up. I edited my initial question with the output of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if PHP supports this parameter passing or not so change:

```
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
              ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
              ->performRequest(), $assoc = TRUE);
```

to:

```
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
              ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
              ->performRequest(), TRUE);
```

This will make sure that the JSON is being converted to an associated array.

Then you need to select the right part of the array to loop over, so change your loop to:

```
foreach($string[0]["trends"] as $items)
{
    echo "Hashtag: ".$items['name']."<br />";

}
```

Comment: I tried this with no change. I also moved the whole thing from localhost to a server to see if this could cause the problems. The result is always a white page with no results. I never thought it could be so damn difficult to grab some hashtags.

Comment: It shouldn't be..! What do you get if you `var_dump($string["trends"][0]["name"]);`

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry for the late reply. My girlfriend had to got to hospital. When I insert the var_dump I just get "NULL" on a white page.

Comment: No problem. Just need to find the right path in the result array. Try `var_dump($string[0]["trends"][0]["name"]);`

Comment: This one looks much better. The output is `string(12) "#alsich10war"` and that`s the first trending topic in Germany right now.

Comment: Great. I have updated the `foreach` in my answer to use that array path. That should be it.

Comment: You are a genius, Andy! This one is working perfectly. I don't know how to thank you for all your patience and helpfulness! Thank's a lot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't used that API so not sure why it has the slightly odd structure. I would have thought it'd be more straight forward but glad this works for you.